# Assigning a const value through inheritance or some other way

Tags: c#, inheritance, dll, constants

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class ExampleClass
{
    public static readonly float updateRate = 12;
}
```

I want to build it in a .dll to use it in my other projects and keep updateRate as a constant (or readonly static).

When I am using the .dll with ExampleClass inside, I want to be able to change the constant through the project that uses the .dll and through classes that inherit the abstract class ExampleClass .

I tried adding virtual, but it is not valid for static readonly nor for const. I explored constant methods, but it seems like C# does not implement those.

Is there a way I can allow the programmer that uses the ExampleClass.dll to change the value of updateRate, possibly by inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of constant is unchangeable. You can't change a constant once it's declared. In fact, every reference to a constant is replaced by it's value at compile time.

`static readonly` is not a constant - however it is readonly and therefor can't be changed.  Also, static members are not exactly inherited - they belong to the class they where declared on, and can't be overriden as you realized yourself.

What you can do, however, is to get the value from app.config. This way, every project that use this dll can have it's own value for this `static readonly` field:

```
public static readonly float updateRate = 
    float.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["updateRate"]);
```

Comment: I was hoping for a different solution that doesn't involve the app.config, but for the time being this is the best solution.